# Can the default value of a recoil atom be an object of objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

Can I create a recoil atom with default value as an object of object? See the below code for reference.

```
export const formState = atom({
  key: "formState",
  default: {
    name: {
       firstName: "",
       lastName: ""
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70692453/438273). Note: there's a missing `}` before the closing parentheses in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAKFElkQwwGAGjhYCKUuQjAcAZRiCUNOg2atpszly7SAdgXhpoIBUrgBeOIIYAKBFzhwA1igCeALjgAiY1FOKMCjewo5wqJi4MF4OTk56GCAoMWFxtMBQhgByick+IalxOIQwOUle3gVpVKFONVxUAJTcXGhYepTAEHpwAIJgYHC2jV6kFDAAdGOUAKI4KEl68LFw+oZwANqGSqISMGZBALqWYhJSMvKBKLZ+AUrNOk5r8FhgSEoAYhnZuSc336Vcl5DFBgHoAOYjOAANxkSEsAD44HsDtdbqjEUMVk4Jrj0VdanEEuVEIUcXiTKiJsSUIS0mgAWVaYV6nVGg8ws9EAzMoCkjQrNsgtTchw4AB6cXImCgiFhVgwLBQHq2AA8SGA0IRX15cBpMR5P35qvFGq1DyoXCAA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';
import {atom, useRecoilState} from 'recoil';

const formState = atom({
  key: "formState",
  default: {
    name: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    },
  },
});

function App (): React.ReactElement {
  const [state, setState] = useRecoilState(formState);

  const updateFirstName = (firstName: string): void => setState(formState => ({
    ...formState,
    name: {
      ...formState.name,
      firstName,
    },
  }));

  const {firstName} = state.name; // string
  return (<div>First name: {firstName}</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. When I tried to update formState using setFormState({ ...formState, formState.name.firstName: "first name' }), I couldn't and the compiler is giving an error on formState.name.firstName.

Comment: @ManishKumar I added an example of how to change just the `firstName` in the nested state object. Does this answer your question?